# Deleting rows from a table on a linked server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have created a linked server named [abc]. this linked server has a table named [Shipment_data] . Following are the columns in [Shipment_data] table: [start_date], [end_date],[route_type]

I want to delete the rows from this table where start_date and end_date is null.

But it looks like the normal delete operation does not work for tables on linked servers:

I tried the following codes, but no luck. Below are my codes and the error messages that i am getting for the same:

method1:

```
Declare @deleteRow nvarchar(max)
Declare @linkedServerName nvarchar(max)
Set @linkedServerName = 'abc'
Set @DeleteRow = 'Delete from ' + @LinkedServerName + '...Shipment_data where [Start_Date] is null and [End_Date] is null'

Set @sql = 'exec ' + @LinkedServerName + '...sp_executesql ' + (@DeleteRow)

exec (@sql)
```

error message:

> OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "abc" returned message "Could not delete from specified tables.".
>   Msg 7320, Level 16, State 2, Line 12
>   Cannot execute the query "DELETE FROM `Shipment_data` " against OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "abc".

Method2:Direct method

```
DELETE FROM [abc]...[Shipment_data]
  WHERE Start_Date is null and End_date is null
```

error message:

> OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "abc" returned message "Bookmark is invalid.".
>   Msg 7346, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Cannot get the data of the row from the OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "abc".

Can someone please help me with a way to accomplish this on MS-SQL?

Comment: That first statement looks concerning open to Injection.

Comment: You should take a look on openquery
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openquery-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I assume you are trying to delete rows from either an MS-Access database, or some other Office type database?  From my experience this "invalid bookmark" error is related to security.  Can you use your linked server to `SELECT` or `UPDATE` data?  In other words is it only `DELETE` giving you problems?

Comment: @RichardHansell In my example, the linked server is an excel spreadsheet. I am able to perform Select operation on this linked server. Cannot execute any Update query or Delete query. throws an error saying:

OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "Zev" returned message "Could not delete from specified tables.".
Msg 7320, Level 16, State 2, Line 17
Cannot execute the query "DELETE FROM `[Shipment_data]` " against OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "ABC".

Comment: Is this is a inherent bug in the provider itself? It is not working for any operations(except Select) at all like Update, Delete, Insert into..

Comment: What user has your linked server been set up to use?  Is it using the "current security context" (or however it's worded)?  Does the user in the linked server have full access to the folder where the Excel file lives?  It certainly can work, so there's no "bug" in the provider, but using linked servers to talk to Excel can be flaky.

Comment: You also might need to give the user access to a folder on the SQL Server as well.  I'm not sure if this is only for MS-Access, but there should be a folder like `$AppData\Local\Temp` on the actual server that SQL Server runs on (or your laptop/ PC if it's a local installation), and you "might" need access to that, as it's utilised by the ACE provider.  This would also explain why you can `SELECT` but not `DELETE` or `UPDATE`.

Comment: Here's a similar issue, but it's talking about Access rather than Excel: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83211/how-to-update-delete-insert-with-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-as-linked-server-in-sq

Comment: I tried all the possible methods as applicable to excel file, like granting permissions to the temp folder . The other thing I found is that I am unable to establish linked server connection with Windows authentication, but can create linked server using SQL server authentication. 

I also tried the methods described in the links below that I found while browsing stuffs related to this:

https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-create-and-configure-a-linked-server-in-sql-server-management-studio/

No luck with this too! issue is certainly with permissions, but not sure where is that issue lying